# Google Maps. Change style after Click

Tags: jquery, maps

I would like to change the Style of the Map on the fly.
But its not working...

function change() {

map.setOptions({styles: [{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":65},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":30},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-97}]}]});

}

jsfiddle.net/9cLjg/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the map var is undefined because is it local to init function, if you make the map variable global you can do this.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nA7gr/

Comment: Crazy. Its so easy! Thanks a lot!